# Displaying two rows that differ by one value but are otherwise identical

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, union, common-table-expression

I am doing a databases course and I have a question that I don't seem to be able to get the answer right to.

There are 3 tables:

```
country(code, iso_abbreviation, name)
area(name, city, country_code, latitude, longitude, elevation)
attraction(name, type, city, country_name, latitude, longitude, elevation)
```

Now, the question asks this: areas are found in both the attraction and area tables. List

```
(country_abbreviation, area_name, latitude, longitude, elevation)
```

for all the areas above 5000 feet elevation. As there may be some inconsistency between the area and attraction data, latitude, longitude and elevation might differ. In such cases, display both variants of the data.

So I came up with the query below, but I'm not sure it pairs them up correctly and it also doesn't split the data into two rows where one of the (`latitude, longitude, elevation`) elements is different.

```
SELECT country.iso_abbreviation as country_abbreviation, area.name as name, 
area.latitude, area.longitude, area.elevation
FROM area JOIN country on country.code = area.country_code
      JOIN attraction on area.name = attraction.name
WHERE area.elevation > 10000

UNION 

SELECT DISTINCT country.iso_abbreviation as country_abbreviation, area.name, 
attraction.latitude, attraction.longitude, attraction.elevation
FROM area JOIN country on country.code = area.state_code
      JOIN attraction on area.name = attraction.name
WHERE attraction.elevation > 10000 ORDER BY country_abbreviation
;
```

Could someone please help me out with this?

Comment: Please put the second, unrelated question into a separate question. You can always link to this one for context. As to your main q: it is unclear. How are the tables related? Declare primary and foreign keys please. Add your version of Postgres. Fix the mismatch between 5000 & 10000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would do what you describe:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT c.iso_abbreviation AS country_abbreviation
        , a.name, a.latitude, a.longitude, a.elevation
   FROM   area       a
   JOIN   country    c ON c.code = a.country_code
   WHERE  a.elevation > 5000
   )
SELECT * FROM cte
UNION
SELECT c.country_abbreviation
     , t.name, t.latitude, t.longitude, t.elevation
FROM   cte        c
JOIN   attraction t USING (name)     -- assuming name links area & attraction (?)
ORDER  BY country_abbreviation, name -- (?)
```

But honestly, the table layout as well as the task you have been given seem unclear.

- Using a [common table expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html) to reuse results from first query.
- [`UNION` (as opposed to `UNION ALL`)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-union.html) removes full duplicates automatically